# Checking if exist in List

Tags: c#

I created a method where i take a random row from ma database and put it into new List, if the method will be used again, it will check if the random row was selected before and chose another one, like drawing without repetition.The program compile, but dont work. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
TABUEntities baza = new TABUEntities();
IList AlreadyChosen = new List<IList>();


public List<HASLA> RandomWords()
        {

            List<HASLA> dane = baza.HASLA.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1).ToList();


            if (AlreadyChosen.Contains(dane))
            {
                RandomWords();
            }
            AlreadyChosen.Add(dane);

            return dane;      
        }
```

Comment: Please explain the "don't work" part in more details.

Comment: *The program compile, but dont work* What do you mean by doesn't work exactly? You need to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: How is `AlreadyChosen` supposed to contain a `List` you just created?

Comment: AlreadyChosen should be a List<HASLA> as I see it and put a return; below the `RandomWords();`

Comment: dont work it means, that the method put inside the List AlreadyChosen a new object from database but dont check if the object already exist there.

Comment: You are creating a new object every time you call `RandomWords` - it can't exist in `AlreadyChosen` since the object didn't exist before

Comment: so how i suppese to do this? any hint?

Comment: I think a for loop maybe more appropriate than recursion. You may also want to check that all rows have not already been selected - otherwise either a for loop or recursive technique may never return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (AlreadyChosen.Any(a=>a.SomeUniqueProperty == dane.SomeUniqueProperty))
```

You have to search by some `unique` property like `Id` to make sure you can find the object. Also if you want to use `Contains` then you will have to implement and override the `IComparable` interface and methods, or pass a custom comparer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TABUEntities baza = new TABUEntities();
List<HASLA> AlreadyChosen = new List<HASLA>();
public List<HASLA> RandomWords()
{



    List<HASLA> rw = new List<HASLA>();
    rw.addRange(AlreadyChosen);

    HASLA selectedObj = baza.HASLA.Where(y => !AlreadyChosen.Contains(y)).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();

    if ((selectedObj == null)) {
        return rw;
    } else {
        if (AlreadyChosen.Contains(selectedObj)) {
            return RandomWords();
        } else {
            AlreadyChosen.add(selectedObj);
            return RandomWords();
        }
    }

}
```